Route parameter for modal dialog using unplugin-vue-router
I'd like to create modal dialog pop-up window with it's own url.
Having table of server items I'd like to open one item and trigger pop-up with it's own url with fetched server item details. The pop-up can be triggered also directly from url and the item list will render behind it.
I have achieved this earlier with named router views using Vue js and Vuetify v-dialog. I wonder if I can reproduce it using unplugin-vue-router.
Previous available approaches:

how to open a vuetify dialog using routes from vue router

https://dev.to/berniwittmann/handling-dialogs-with-vue-router-29ji


It doesn't need to be modal utilised Vuetify library but generally I'm looking for solution narrowed only to unplugin-vue-router library.
Cheers!

The question isn't specific enough. "Having table of server items I'd like to open one item and trigger pop-up with it's own url with fetched server item details" - how  is this supposed to work, how do different urls affect the modal exactly? "I have achieved this earlier" - please, show your current attempt, linking to articles is not enough. What does prevent you from doing this with unplugin-vue-router? You could put this logic to [id].vue or handle a subtree of routes in a special way like https://uvr.esm.is/guide/extending-routes.html , but again, this depends on urls
